# How can I get today's calendar date instead of system's displayed date

Tags: jquery

I want the current calendar date instead of system date.

Hw can I get it using jquery.

For example, current date is "27/07/2016" and my system date is "20/07/2016". If I give,

```js
var date = new Date();
```

It will take the system date.How can I get the current calendar date if system date different also.

Comment: Please define "current calendar date".

Comment: You might need to explain the difference - perhaps an example?

Comment: define the difference!

Comment: Are you creating your site using any server-side tech? (eg php, .net mvc).  If it's not time critical (only date) then you can specify the current date when you build the page.  eg for js inside a Razor view: `var today = '@(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))';`.   Knowing how you generate the page will provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m  var today = '@(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))'; this is showing invalid or unexpected token error.

Comment: Just wondering - did you read the rest of the comment?  Are you using a **Razor cshtml MVC View**?  Specifically: **What, if any, server-side code are you using?**

Answer (score 0):

Create or use a web service to fetch the exact date or time:

```js
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/').done(function(data) {
  console.log( data.date );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should keep in mind that server timezone can be different to your system one, so you have to pass the required timezone as a parameter to the web service.

Comment: I can't use 'http://date.jsontest.com/' this url in project. Is any other way is there. But it is woking fine.